# Прототипы функций и заголовочные файлы

Tags: c++, компиляция

Может пожалуйста кто нибудь мне объяснить? К примеру я пишу свою библиотеку(очень грубо сказано).  Так вот, у меня есть три файла "main.cpp", "f.cpp", "f.h".
Так вот в "f.cpp" у меня лежит реализация функции foo() и в ней я подключаю "f.h".

```
#include"f.h"
int foo()
{
    return 1;
}
```

В файле "f.h" у меня подключаются необходимые библиотеки, и лежит прототип функции foo().

```
#include<iostream>
#include<Windows.h>
int foo();
```

И в третьем файле мы подключаем
"f.h" и выполняем определенные действия.

```
#include"f.h"
int main()
{
    std::cout << foo();
    return 0;
}
```

Почему мы подключаем только .h-файл с прототипами функций, ведь при подключении ТОЛЬКО .h-файла компилятор не поймет где лежит реализация этих функций и по идее должен выдать ошибку, но он не выдает никаких ошибок.

Comment: А почему вы думаете, что компилятору нужна _реализация_ функции `foo`, чтобы скомпилировать `main.cpp`?

Comment: @Джони Кэтсвилл, ну а как выполнить что-то если не знаешь, как это работает. Мы же только даем команду компилятору о существовании этой функции, но что делать если эта функция вызывается компилятор не знает, ведь она не описана.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

То, что для "простого программиста" работа компилятора, на самом деле три больших этапа - препроцессор, собственно компиляция и линковка.

На первом этапе компилятор подставляет include (да, грубо говоря, он просто копипастит содержимое по месту) и разворачивает макросы.

На втором этапе полученные "большие" cpp файлы (единицы компиляции) переводятся в бинарный вид. На этот момент те функции, для которых нет тела ещё не страшны. Компилятору нужно знать только их сигнатуру, что бы организовать правильный вызов (то есть, заполнить стек/регистры и подставить call). Правда самого адреса ещё может не быть.

И тут вступает линковщик, который берет все эти скомпилированные файлы, нужные внешние библиотеки, копирует в один большой файл, добавляет туда код/данные, что бы операционная система смогла это запустить и вместо адресов-заглушек подставляет реальные адреса. И вот здесь уже нужно знать, где реально находится вызываемая функция.

BTW, включение windows.h  в свои заголовочные файлы - плохая идея, особенно, если это библиотека.

Comment: Извините, но хотелось бы еще уточнить: компилятор переводит все cpp и h файлы в бинарный вид или только те которые связаны между собой include-ами, например у нас есть файл в котором просто объявляется переменная  int a, но он никуда не подключается и в него ничего не подключается, что с ним происходит в таком случае?

Comment: h файлы не участвуют явно в компиляции. компилируются только cpp файлы (да, системе сборки/компилятору можно объяснить, что файлы с расширением czz - это также cpp файлы)   Если h файл никак не включен ни в один другой файл, то он ничего не делает. Другое дело, если один хедер включен в другой, а тот уже включен в cpp, который компилируются. В этом случае будет сделана "двойная вставка" и в результирующем "большом cpp" файле будут они оба.

Comment: То есть не важно подключаем мы файл или нет, если у нас в одном файле есть вызов неописанной функции, а в другом файле у нас лежит ее описание мы можем даже не подключать этот файл?

Comment: Просто мне все равно не понятно, каким образом компилятор понимает, что именно в этом файле лежит реализация функций и именно эти функции соответствуют прототипам описанным в хедере, мы же не подключаем этот файл к хедеру.

Comment: а компилятор это не должен понимать. Это задача линковщика. Компилятор только оставляет заметку линковщику "вот здесь нужно вставить функцию с таким именем и такими параметрами (гуглить "манглинг"), а вот си компилятор только имя". А уже линковщик собирает список имеющихся функций и ищет подходящую в каждое место. Ещё раз, это не компиляторное дело, это дело линковщика, а он это дело делает по именам. Поэтому, в хедере могут быть объявления функций, реализации которых по факту разбросаны по десятку других файлов.

Comment: То есть получается мы даже можем не подключать никакие заголовочные файлы с прототипами, линковщик сам найдет эти реализации разбросанные по файлам?

Comment: Получается смысла в подключении файлов при помощи директивы include вообще нету, ведь в любом случае поискав по файлам компоновщик найдет реализацию.

Comment: в си - да, там компилятор выругается, но линковщик попробует найти и сложить вместе. Если компилятор правильно угадал сигнатуру, то все будет ок. В с++ пошли дальше и решили защитить программиста от подобного и компилятор хочет видеть реальную сигнатуру. Но никто не мешает прям перед вызовом написать объявление функции и не подключать include - все скомпилируется и будет работать

Comment: Извините за мою тупость, это последний вопрос. Почему если мы в одном файле  объявили функцию, а в другом попытались вызвать ее без прототипа, то линковщик выдаст ошибку? И спасибо вам огромное, вы очень сильно мне помогли)

Comment: мне кажется, Вы немного смешали в кучу определение, объявление компилятор и линковщик. Линковщик выдаст ошибку, если он не может найти подходящую по имени функцию (ещё раз упоминаю манглинг). На заголовочные файлы ему побоку. Компилятор же когда видит вызов функции очень хочет видеть сигнатуру (объявление = имя+параметры) этой функции, что бы правильно в стек напихать параметры.

Answer (score 2):

По сути процесс простой. Сначала компилятор компилирует каждый файл и для каждого файла создает обьектный файл, в котором вместо вызовов функций находятся какие-то идентификаторы (зависят от компилятора). После компиляции все эти обьектные файлы передаются линковщику, который заменяет эти идентификаторы адресами уже скомпилированных функций. Потом добавляет код запуска и (если есть) библиотеки и создает исполняемый файл.

Answer (score 1):

При компиляции в заголовках находятся *предварительные* объявления функций. Это даёт компилятору понять типы входящие и типы результата функции, но в оъектном файле (**.obj** или **.o**) только прописываются имена этих функций.

После создания этих объектных файлов начинается **линковка**. Она связывает эти имена с реальными указателями внутри выполняемого файла.